# Multiple Vendors; fetching the products per vendor

Tags: category, multi-vendor

Obviously lots of posts here are made about multi vendors, this is not a problem I've got a module running for this.

What I am wondering if someone can push me in the right direction without screwing up; I would like to add category-like pages, which contain all products from a "vendor". Or easier said per admin user.

Anyone have an idea to push me in the right direction?

Vendors will use multiple global categories, so i can't just create category pages to resolve this.

Any hints on fixing them to appear in the menu / creating the overview page will be great.

Comment: i know its quite delayed answer but we are the the developers of magento marketplace extension where vendor have their own profile and product collection page you may check here https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't use categories for data which is clearly an attribute.

Assign an attribute for the vendor, then implement a shop by attribute style of functionality.

This will be easier to manage, will scale and is the intended design.

Comment: You mean that every vendor has to add an attribute to their items to say it's theirs?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm not sure of the ACL's you are using for the respective site admins, but you could easily add an observer the product save (for anything they interact with), to set a multi-select attribute with their given vendor ID.